# What is the oposite of EXPECT_CALL?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, googletest, assert, googlemock

I have some expectations like `EXPECT_CALL (...)`

```
EXPECT_CALL(t1, foo()).Times(1);
```

I want to create the oposite.
I expect that a certain function **won't be executed**.

What is the method I should use?
Something like `EXPECT_NOT_CALL (...)` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In GTest something similar to `EXPECT_NOT_CALL` doesn't exist however, there are several options to receive this behaviour:

1.Create a [StrictMock](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#The_Nice,_the_Strict,_and_the_Naggy). In `StrictMock` any unexpected called cause a failure.

2.Use `.Times(0)`:

```
EXPECT_CALL(t1, foo()).Times(0);
```

In this option you use the count mechanism however, it checks if the value is `0`.(so any call leads a failure...)

3.Use method `2` and create a `Macro`:

```
#define EXPECT_NOT_CALL(a,b)     EXPECT_CALL(a, b).Times(0);
```